# PHP variable length arguments?

Tags: php, function, variadic-functions

In Python and others, there's special syntax for variable length argument lists:

```
def do_something(*args):
    # do something

do_something(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) # arbitrarily long list
```

I was reading the PHP manual, and it said this:

> PHP 4 and above has support for
>   variable-length argument lists in
>   user-defined functions. This is really
>   quite easy, using the func_num_args(),
>   func_get_arg(), and func_get_args()
>   functions.
>
> No special syntax is required, and
>   argument lists may still be explicitly
>   provided with function definitions and
>   will behave as normal.

I get the first part. You can pass as many arguments as you'd like to a function that takes no arguments, then get them as an array using `func_get_args()`, etc. I don't really get what the second part is saying, though.

So, my question is, is there some special syntax for variable length arguments, or some best practice that I don't know about? The approach that the manual suggests seems kludgey at best and makes your function seem like it's taking no arguments (unless I'm doing it wrong). Should I not be trying to use this language feature at all?

Comment: @Shrapnel that's kind of a PHP philosophy, isn't it? Who cares about everyone else, I'll just produce whatever?

Comment: PHP supports comments. That's enough. If you want to code, not *to chatter* about code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike Python's `*` operator or C#'s `params` keyword, in PHP you don't even have to specify the variable length arguments. As the second part starts off, "No special syntax is required."

As to the rest of the second paragraph: if you want to specify any required or unrelated arguments that come before the variable-length arguments, specify them in your function signature so your function can handle those. Then to get the variable-length arguments, remove the required variables from `func_get_args()`, like so:

```
function func($required) {
    // Contains all arguments that come after $required
    // as they were present at call time
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
}
```

You don't have to do this (you can still slice from `func_get_args()` and use its different elements accordingly), but it does make your code more self-documenting.

Comment: I was more thinking of having a name for the variable length arguments, but thank you, this is useful info.

Comment: It's a cool pattern but `array_slice(func_get_args(), 1)` will throw a warning in PHP 5.3 and a fatal error in 5.4 http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php — the fix is to wrap `funct_get_args()` in parentheses like `array_splice( (func_get_args()), 1 )`

Answer (score 18):

Here is a more realistic example:

```
function Average()
{
    $result = 0;
    $arguments = func_get_args();

    foreach ($arguments as $argument)
    {
        $result += $argument;
    }

    return ($result / max(1, func_num_args()));
}

Average(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // 3
```

This is called a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Answer (score 8):

Since **PHP 5.6**, a variable argument list can be specified with the `...` operator.

```
function do_something($first, ...$all_the_others)
{
    var_dump($first);
    var_dump($all_the_others);
}

do_something('this goes in first', 2, 3, 4, 5);

#> string(18) "this goes in first"
#>
#> array(4) {
#>   [0]=>
#>   int(2)
#>   [1]=>
#>   int(3)
#>   [2]=>
#>   int(4)
#>   [3]=>
#>   int(5)
#> }
```

As you can see, the `...` operator collects the variable list of arguments in an array.

If you need to pass the variable arguments to another function, the `...` can still help you.

```
function do_something($first, ...$all_the_others)
{
    do_something_else($first, ...$all_the_others);
    // Which is translated to:
    // do_something_else('this goes in first', 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

---

Since **PHP 7**, the variable list of arguments can be forced to be **all** of the same type too.

```
function do_something($first, int ...$all_the_others) { /**/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no special syntax for variable length argument functions.

Simply use the func_num_args() and func_get_args() functions to get the arguments.

Example:

```
function callMe(){

    if(func_num_args() == 0){
        echo 'No arguments =)';
    }else{
        var_dump(func_get_args());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second portion is basically saying that once you start using the variable argument functions, then

```
function average() { ... }
function average(arg1, arg2, arg3) { ... }
```

work identically, just that the second version has 3 arguments explicity listed. That's all, don't try to read more into a man page than there is.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this to avoid kept changing function, and avoid error on argument order

```
function any_function($ops=array())
{
}

$ops = array('name'=>1, 'type'=>'simplexml', 'callback'=>...);
```

Comment: Well, you also lose the benefit of getting an error raised if the user passes the wrong arguments - or misspells one of the arguments. pros and cons.

Comment: I would not said not true, I would prefer associate key which should more be readable to index key

Comment: Personally, I just hate passing arrays to functions. it's too long to type all these delimiters

Comment: also auto-complete will not be aware of the parameters (for ide users)