# How should one signify to a caller in PHP that a function accepts a variable number of arguments?

Tags: php

It has come down from high places that a webapp I've been working on needs to move to stored procedures for everything it does in the database. To that end, I have taken to enforcing that constraint by writing a new database layer on top of mysqli which exposes only the "allowed" behavior. Consider what I have so far:

```
class Cas_Database
{
    private $mysqli;
    private $mode;

    public function __construct(...)
    {
    ... //Ommitted
    }

    public function Transaction(/* callable */ $func)
    {
        $mysqli->autocommit(false);
        try
        {
            $func($this);
            $mysqli->commit();
            $mysqli->autocommit(true);
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $mysqli->rollback();
            $mysqli->autocommit(true);
            throw $ex;
        }
    }

    public function MultiProcedure($schema, $func)
    {
        $args = func_num_args() - 2;
        $sql = "CALL `{$this->mode}_{$schema}`.`{$func}` (";
        if ($args >= 1)
        {
            $sql .= '? ';
            for ($idx = 1; $idx < $args; ++$idx)
            {
                $sql .= ', ?';
            }
        }
        $sql .= ')';
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $typeStr = '';
        $refArgs = array(null);
        for ($idx = 0; $idx < $args; ++$idx)
        {
            $argIndex = $idx + 2;
            $arg = func_get_arg($argIndex);
            $refArgs[] = &$arg;
            if (is_int($arg))
            {
                $typeStr .= 'i';
            }
            else if (is_float($arg))
            {
                $typeStr .= 'f';
            }
            else
            {
                $typeStr .= 's';
            }
        }
        $refArgs[0] = $typeStr;
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $refArgs);
        if ($stmt->execute() !== true)
        {
            $error = $stmt->error;
            $stmt->close();
            throw new Exception($error);
        }
        $mysqlAnswer = $stmt->get_result();
        $results = array();
        while (($answerRow = $mysqlAnswer->fetch_assoc()) !== null)
        {
            $results[] = $answerRow;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Note how the MultiProcedure function expects multiple arguments from the user. Is there a way to specify that in the contract of the function so that users know what to look for, or  are they forced to read the method to find out?

Comment: No, there is not. Why don't you use an array instead?

Comment: Why not use the PhpDoc `@param <type> $paramname Description...` syntax?

Comment: @Shef: How does one use that for a parameter that has no name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP variable length arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578975/php-variable-length-arguments)

Comment: Isn't that something you put in the documentation for your code, so that people using it can find out the details they need? PHP will trigger a fatal error if an incorrect number of arguments was passed.

Comment: @FrederikCreemers: Yes. I'll just go on and write comments about everything. Oh wait, there exists a @ param syntax that gives callers and IDEs information about my code? Wow, I wish I had known that before just randomly commenting everywhere. /sarcasm Seriously, if the answer is "no" then the answer is "no". There's nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: @BillyONeal You use it in the method's documentation, just like you would for a method which has the parameters. It should show up in the documentation of your IDE. Write the parameter name as `$arg1...$argN` and in the description write that there can be any number of arguments.

Comment: @Shef: Why not make that an answer? (And now that you point that out, http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use phpDocumentor's [`@param`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html) syntax to mention it in the documentation of the method. It will show up when you generate the docs, and in the developer's IDE at the time the method will be used.

Write the parameter name as `$paramn,...` and in the description write that there can be any number of arguments.

Comment: Hmm... the [docs](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html) say the syntax should be `$paramN,...`

Comment: @BillyONeal You should use that syntax. I do use the one I suggested, because it is more obvious to me and the people who work with me, but you should stick to the docs. :)